# What do polymorphic associations solve?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

Let's assume I have an application with a "favorites" feature, where users can add a document, note, or comment to his favorites list.

In my mind..

- User `has_many` Favorites
- Favorite `belongs_to` a User

---

- Document `belongs_to` a Favorite
- Note `belongs_to` a Favorite
- Comment `belongs_to` a Favorite

What's the problem with this type of association and how would polymorphic associations help?

Answer (score 1):

because then your Favorite instance will not know what it is favouriting :) 
it knows that it `has_one :note`, but also has_one `:comment`, or? but not both surely.

**polymorphic association the opposite way** helps because it will express that a `Favorite` object belongs_to `:favorited` object that is polymorphic cos it can be any class the name of which will be stored in the `:favorited_type` string db column, so your favorite object will know that it favors a note or document or comment.

with some code

```
class Note
  has_many :favorites, :as => :favorited
  has_many :fans, :through => :favorites, :source => :user
end

class Discussion
  has_many :favorites, :as => :favorited
  has_many :fans, :through => :favorites, :source => :user
end

class Comment
  has_many :favorites, :as => :favorited
  has_many :fans, :through => :favorites, :source => :user
end

class Favorite
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :favorited, :polymorphic => true # note direction of polymorphy
end

class User
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :favorite_notes, :through =>  :favorites, :source => favorited, :source_type => "Note"
  has_many :favorite_comments, :through =>  :favorites, :source => favorited, :source_type => "Comment"
  has_many :favorite_discussions, :through =>  :favorites, :source => favorited, :source_type => "Discussion"

end
```

(just set up your db correctly) this design is standard for such usecase of favoriting.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  What problem does a polymorphic association solve?  And if you can, please describe your answer in the context of my example (unless my example does not relate, in which case, what example does?).  Thank you.

Comment: I think I did explain in the context of your example exactly. I added some code, hope it helps.

Comment: As I said, I'm not sure I follow with respects to your answer fitting my question.  Once again, what problem does a polymorphic association solve?

Comment: Try to code it with relations you suggest under 'In my mind' and then you will understand. Hint: give me the method call to get a users favorite discussions.

Comment: Okay, so what if I did this: User has_many Favorites, Note has_many Favorites.  On the flip side: Favorite belongs_to User, Favorite belongs_to Note.  Now each Favorite will reference a User and a Note (or other model).  Then I can find a User.first.favorites.each {|f| f.note}

Comment: I guess the thing I'm asking is... in this example, Favorite is just a join table, so why not use a regular join table... why make it polymorphic?

Comment: "Favorite will reference a User and a Note (or other model)." exactly: you say or other model. how can you have other model? only if you use polymorphism or if you allow belongs_to :discussion, belongs_to :comment in your Favorite task, but that makes it clumsy to express that it only ever belongs to one of them at a time.